# AngularJS and $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to understand the lifetime of `scopes` in Angular and was wondering if doing `$rootScope.$on` or `$rootScope.$watch` ever goes out of scope (in the traditional sense)?

Does Angular have any type of Garbage Collection or anything like that?

Do you have to worry about releasing objects ($scopes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entirety of angular scopes is a rather large piece of documentation, but you can start [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) or [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

The short, lofty answer is that angular inspects your modules (`angular.module('myapp')`) to create a complex tree of dependencies. Then the DOM is parsed to identify "ng" tags or other custom directives, which go through a compile phase (that constructs the custom HTML) and a linking phase (that generates a scope and attaches it to that element). That is about 1/100th of what really goes on, but it's a start.

Angular does perform garbage collection, but almost all of it happens behind the scenes. When a $scope is scheduled to be removed, one of the last things it does is fire a $scope.$destroy(), which you can hook into with `$scope.$on('$destroy', function() { .. })` to perform any cleanup. Then again, in most instances you don't have to worry about cleanup or "releasing" anything, as angular takes care of that as well.

:Edit:

I also stumbled across this, which explains it best by far-- [understanding scopes](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).